# Google Oauth 2.0 authentication for limited input device not working

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, android-youtube-api

I am trying to use a custom java application of mine to upload videos to my youtube account via an access limited device like a Raspberry pi running as a server.

For this I am using the [Google Oauth 2.0 for limited input device](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#devices) as a reference.

Here I am facing following problem:

1. After getting the Device code via following similar call (Step 2 from the link):

   > ```
   > POST /o/oauth2/device/code HTTP/1.1
   > Host: accounts.google.com
   > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   >
   > client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
   > scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube
   > ```
2. Google Oauth server responds with 'user_code' and 'verification_url' (Step 3 from the link):

   > {   "device_code" : "4/L9fTtLrhY96442SEuf1Rl3KLFg3y",   "user_code" :
   >   "a9xfwk9c",   "verification_url" : "http://www.google.com/device",
   >   "expires_in" : "1800"   "interval" : 5, }
3. Now I am giving the requisite permission by opening the url as responded by google server.
4. Finally I am trying to get the access token from Google server (Step 4 from the link) by posting similar request:

> ```
> POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1    
> Host: accounts.google.com
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
> client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSem&
> code=4/YMSlR3fSCC1NtUh073DuZKTJJ3ss&
> grant_type=http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0
> ```

**but instead of getting the 'access_token' as response I am getting the following :**

> ```
> Status Code:400 Response: {   "error" : "invalid_request", 
> "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" }
> ```

**Note :** With or without url encoding, my problem stays the same.

**Can someone please help me as to whether it's the Google Oauth 2.0 api is buggy or my request is faulty?**

*****************************************UPDATE***************************************

I tried the same steps with some alternative tools instead of my custom java application, so I tried [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), the surprise is as follows:

1. All of the calls worked right as mentioned by [Google Oauth 2.0 for limited input device](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication#devices) for curl.
2. Same issue was observed with Fiddler as was with my custom java app.

**I am still unable to figure out the difference yet, still need help.**

**************UPDATE#2****************

Fiddler request:

(url encoded, obscured client secret)

(One can get oauth credentials (client_id and client_secret) by following [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application))

```
POST HTTP/1.1
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=308065994473-ur9dd7003ajs6mvr5s4kqnugr6j8tsf2.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=4%2FWR-qiTquqB0e4-0LCy0-7rZ2kkE2&grant_type=http%3A%2F%2Foauth.net%2Fgrant_type%2Fdevice%2F1.0

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

(non url encoded, obscured client secret)

```
POST HTTP/1.1
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?client_id=308065994473-ur9dd7003ajs6mvr5s4kqnugr6j8tsf2.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&code=4/WR-qiTquqB0e4-0LCy0-7rZ2kkE2&grant_type=http://oauth.net/grant_type/device/1.0
```

**Java code project is available at (maven project, check the test case for the Oauth calls):**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8ltWBtPF-DVMDZFNHNMZXpCQlk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is wrong, you should use `grant_type=authorization_code` as [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) says.

Comment: Tried your suggestion, still same issue.

Comment: Delete the line break in the post data, so use `client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSem&code=4/YMSlR3fSCC1NtUh073DuZKTJJ3ss&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=your_encoded_redirectURI`

Comment: The calls worked fine exactly as per Google's reference doc when I used 'curl', but it's not working when I use fiddler or my custom java app, I have updated the question, please have a look.

Comment: Please check Update#2 in the question.

Comment: Will add the java code on suitable forum and provide the link.

Comment: Wrong java code, you should not add params in the request path, set params in Entity like this`httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));`